# SQLite triggers, do bindings get passed to triggers?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, view, android-sqlite

I am doing some database operations in Android, I am working on creating an update trigger when an attempt to update a view is called. Simple question, Do the original WHERE bindings sent to the view also get sent to the trigger as well?

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDatabaseTools.getWritableDatabase();
    int numberOfRows;

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case ProviderContract.TABLE_1:
            numberOfRows = database.update(DatabaseContract.TABLE_1_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case ProviderContract.TABLE_2:
            numberOfRows = database.update(DatabaseContract.TABLE_2_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case ProviderContract.TABLE_3:
            numberOfRows = database.update(DatabaseContract.TABLE_3_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case ProviderContract.TABLE_4:
            numberOfRows = database.update(DatabaseContract.TABLE_4_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case ProviderContract.VIEW_1_CHILD:
            numberOfRows = database.update(DatabaseContract.VIEW_1_CHILD_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
    database.close();
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "bindings"? Show some code.

Comment: A binding, like when you add data onto an SQL statement and it gets inserted where you have "?" in your statement. All i have is generic ContentProvider code, pretty standard. I will be using it to perform an update on a view, also providing a where clause. I need that where clause passed to the trigger. Edited post with some code.

Comment: What does the trigger need the WHERE clause for? What is it going to do with it?

Comment: I have a 2 tables, one column is used as a foreign key to the other table. Sometimes i need to update a certain row of that FK, not all the foreign keys of that same value which i believe the update command does without a where clause. So basically I just need the update to work on a specific row at a time.

Comment: A trigger gets (only) the old and new values in the row to be updated. It might be possible to help you if you show the relevant part of the table definitions, the trigger, and what it should do.